# How to open another channel from our Roku channel

Tags: roku, television

hi I am trying to open my another channel with user click a button.

I want my other channel to load. I have no clue how this can be don. some people suggest me to do it through deeplink but all in vain. so how I can do this in Roku.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hi you can go to another channel from your own channel but this will not load both channels parallelly. your running channel will we closed and new channel will be loaded, if channel is installed on your device it will automatically open and if it is not installed add channel screen will be open. here is code for this. (write this code in task)

```js
m.app = CreateObject("roAppManager")
    if m.app.IsAppInstalled(m.top.AdChannelID,"") = true

       params = {contentID:""}
       m.app.LaunchApp(m.top.AdChannelID,"",params)
    else

       m.app.ShowChannelStoreSpringboard(m.top.AdChannelID)
    end if
```

and now run this task and assign channel id to this tasks

```js
    m.OpenOtherChannelTask = createObject("roSGNode", "OpenOtherChannelTask")
    m.OpenOtherChannelTask.AdChannelID = m.channelID
    m.OpenOtherChannelTask.control = "run"
```

also do not forget to add this in your tasks xml file

```html
<interface > 
    <field id="AdChannelID" type="string"/>
  </interface>
```

Hope this will help you.